# Remove link to dashboard page inside rails_admin breadcrumb

Tags: rails-admin

I want to retain rails_admin `breadcumb` as is but **without** a link to dashboard page. I am not clear on how to achieve this. I have tried looking into `rails_admin` codebase but I am not sure how to make this possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out one way would be to hide it via css.

Adding following css in `app/assets/stylesheets/rails_admin/custom/theming.scss` hides the link:

```
ol.breadcrumb li:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

Had to add extra css to correct placement of separator `/`, this override `rails_admin` default `before` selector behaviour:

```
.breadcrumb > li + li:after {
  content: "/ ";
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.breadcrumb > li + li:before {
  content: "";
  padding: 0;
}
```